# how to escape unwanted characters in filename

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

When trying to play an audio file using jplayer, I am getting this error:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://.../AudioFiles/Thorne,%20Grandma%27s%20Goodbye%20excerpt_4.m4a"
```

Now this is the only audio file I have which  comes with this error, I am assuming the reason for this is because that ths file name has a single quote inside the file name as it is known as `Thorne, Grandma's Goodbye excerpt.m4a`.

My question is how to escape unwanted characters in audio file name?

Below is code:

```
$getaudio = 'AudioFiles/' . $_GET['filename'];

$info = pathinfo($dbAudioFile); 

    <script type="text/javascript">   
        $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
          $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            <?php echo $info['extension'];?>: "<?php echo $dbAudioFile; ?>"
          });
        },
        solution:"flash,html",
        swfPath: "jquery",
        supplied: "<?php echo $info['extension'];?>"
      });
    }); 
    </script>
```

`$dbAudioFile` is the filename

Comment: I think in this instance you want urlencode

Comment: @popnoodles It looks like it's properly encoded as %27 in the error message.

Comment: Oh yes. Then I don't see an issue in the basename, perhaps it's elsewhere, like the directory it uses does not actually match the url.